# How to map float to double? SSIS sql task output mapping to variables

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a stored procedure being called that returns a number of float and varchar fields in the resultset.  The result is being saved in an ado recordset obect, then I am trying to save member fields into user variables.  The very first variable mapping is failing.  I set a breakpoint on the foreach container, but cant really see inside the object.  The error Im getting is like this:

> Error: 0xC001F009 at MyRRptLoad: The type of the value being assigned
>   to variable "User::RES_AMOUNT" differs from the current variable type.
>   Variables may not change type during execution. Variable types are
>   strict, except for variables of type Object.

Ive seen one example where expressions were used in the variable mapping.

So Im trying to map my input data which is type float to a user variable, but it doesnt seem to like being set as a double.  The other example was to change the output type from the procedure, but thats not really an option in my case, or at least id really rather not go down that road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just stumbled into, Why oh why does SSIS handle all these data types differently!!!

The broad answer to your question is that SSIS have Four ways in which to read and encode data. What you are doing going from Variable to and SSIS Pipeline Buffer is one of these fun little mismatches. Normally to handle this I use **data conversion tasks** before each of the disparate data type actions.

I know that sounds really painful, but it does work.

For a quick reference the data types change between the following four actions (There may be more)

**SSIS Variable - > SSIS Pipeline Buffer -> OLE DB -> ADO.NET** (And it is of course different from SQL)

For a more in depht read have a look at [this](http://milambda.blogspot.com.au/2014/02/sql-server-integration-services-data.html) website.

Comment: I had stumbled upon that same website in the past.  I ended up making a "wrapper" procedure that loads the output from the main procedure into a table variable, then select my final output from there.  This made it much easier for me to use a dataflow task instead of a sql task and foreach loop to process the records.

Answer (score 0):

As the exception says, you cannot change the data type during mapping. The option you have is to convert the variables/columns in your SP to the target data type, so that you don't have to convert them while mapping. hope it helps.

Comment: What do you think is the SSIS equivalent data type for `float` data?   According to the documentation I've found, it should be `double`.

Comment: Then I don't understand your answer.  If `double` is the equivalent of `float`, why does SSIS consider this a change of datatype during mapping?   Are you saying that there is no SSIS datatype that can receive float data when mapping from a recordset?

Comment: What I just did that works, is have a script task reference the loop variables from my recordset, then build sql statement.  The numeric output values from the stored procedure are pulled into object datatypes (see this http://milambda.blogspot.com/2014/02/sql-server-integration-services-data.html) , then my sql statement I use Decimal.Parse(Dts.Variables["my variable"]) within the string.

Comment: I was going to suggest a script task as a workaround, but I'm curious as to the answer to WHY doesn't the float data implicitly convert to double?